# Unable to load resource file after refreshing the activity in language change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, localization

Don't know what is going wrong but unable to load resource after refreshing the activity, I guess locale is changing but resources are not loading properly

My Code structure is like this

I am supporting the **Hindi** language
[image: After adding my resource file, the structure will look like this]

Here is the code what I have done till now

**LocaleManagerMew.kt**

```
    val SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "MEW_CURRENT_-- USER_LANGUAGE"

    var mEnglishFlag = "en"
    var mHindiFlag = "hi"

    fun setLocale(context: Context?): Context? {
        return updateResources(context, getCurrentLanguage(context))
    }

    inline fun  setNewLocale(context: Context, language: String) {
        persistLanguagePreference(context, language)
        updateResources(context, language)
    }

    inline fun getCurrentLanguage(context: Context?): String {

        context?.let {
            Prefs.Builder()
                .setContext(it)
                .setMode(ContextWrapper.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .setPrefsName(it.packageName)
                .setUseDefaultSharedPreference(true)
                .build()
        }

        val mCurrentLanguage: String? = Prefs.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, mEnglishFlag)
        return mCurrentLanguage ?: ""
    }

    fun persistLanguagePreference(context: Context, language: String?) {

        Prefs.Builder()
            .setContext(context)
            .setMode(ContextWrapper.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .setPrefsName(context.packageName)
            .setUseDefaultSharedPreference(true)
            .build()

        Prefs.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language ?: mHindiFlag)

    }

    fun updateResources(context: Context?, language: String): Context? {

        var contextFun = context

        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val resources = context?.resources
        val configuration = Configuration(resources?.configuration)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            configuration.setLocale(locale)
            contextFun = context?.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
        } else {
            configuration.locale = locale
            resources?.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
        }
        return contextFun
    }
}
```

Note: I am using **Prefs** just to store the Preferences

**Application Class**

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManagerMew.setLocale(base))
}

override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        LocaleManagerMew.setLocale(this)
        Timber.d("onConfigurationChanged: ${newConfig.locale.language}")
}
```

**AndroidManifest.XML**

```
<application
        android:name=".AppName"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
    ...

<activity
            android:name=".intro.IntroActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    ...

</application>
```

**IntroActivity.kt**

On Click of the button, I am changing the language

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.btn_next -> {

                val mCurrentLanguage =
                    LocaleManagerMew.getCurrentLanguage(this@IntroActivity.applicationContext)
                if (mCurrentLanguage == LocaleManagerMew.mEnglishFlag) {
                    showToast("To Hindi")
                    LocaleManagerMew.setNewLocale(
                        this@IntroActivity.applicationContext,
                        LocaleManagerMew.mHindiFlag
                    )
                } else if (mCurrentLanguage == LocaleManagerMew.mHindiFlag) {
                    showToast("To English")
                    LocaleManagerMew.setNewLocale(
                        this@IntroActivity.applicationContext,
                        LocaleManagerMew.mEnglishFlag
                    )
                }
                recreate()
            }
        }
    }
```

The things which I observed
 - After recreate() call, activity's onCreate() calls again, but application class' onConfigurationChanged is not calling

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you refreshing your activity? The app language changes when the app is renewed.

Comment: recereate() doing the same stuff

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution...!!!

Apart from the above methods, we also need to check app level gradle file where `resourse("en")` is there then please remove  it

After removing it, it will work fine...!!!

Comment: Can you please share the code how did you handle this. Because I have the same issue and can't find the solution.

Comment: Just remove the line from the app level gradle file